# Write a batch file to find a .exe file and export to .txt

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that searches a computer for a `.exe` file and exports the findings to a `.txt` file. I would like the computer name to be in the `.txt` file and for the file to say whether or not the `.exe` is located on that computer. Take a look at what i have so far. seems to find `.docx` files no problem.

What am i doing wrong?

```
@echo off
If exist c:\filename.exe echo %COMPUTERNAME% yes >> \\servername\location\test.txt
If NOT exist c:\filename.exe echo %COMPUTERNAME% no >> \\servername\location\test.txt
```

Comment: So it finds docx files using the same code?

Comment: Yes. I created a word doc, called it test and saved it to my desktop. Ran that batch file with PSEXEC and it created the report and said "Yes" it located that test file.

Comment: Did you put the exe you are searching for in the same place?

Comment: @BaliC looks like even if it did not exist, it should still log that fact. We need to know more information. Is NO line getting logged. Are you getting a NO?

Comment: The "No" line is getting created and every file I search for reports as a "No" even though I'm positive it's located on the test machine. I have put the .exe file on my desktop and it reports as a "NO"

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to search the given .exe file in *all folders* of current computer? The Batch file below use a small trick: it assume that the .exe file is located in one of the folders of PATH variable (as usually happen), so the search is immediate:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (filename.exe) do set filePath=%%~$PATH:a
if defined filePath echo %COMPUTERNAME% yes >> \\servername\location\test.txt
if NOT defined filePath echo %COMPUTERNAME% no >> \\servername\location\test.txt
```

**EDIT:** *New version for the whole disk added*

```
@echo off
set filePath=
for /R C:\ /D %%a in (*) do if exist "%%a\filename.exe" set filePath=%%a& goto continue
:continue
if defined filePath echo %COMPUTERNAME% yes >> \\servername\location\test.txt
if NOT defined filePath echo %COMPUTERNAME% no >> \\servername\location\test.txt
```

Comment: I would like to be able to search any computer's C: drive on my network for a certain .exe file and have the report tell me if it exists.

Comment: Where exactly you want to search the .exe file in C: drive? Just in root directory? In directories of PATH variable? In the entire disk?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the problem. It's a proprietary software and can be in any of 3 locations depending on the OS. So I would like to be able to search the whole disk.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following script:

```
Echo OFF
dir G:\XX in (*.*) /b > peru.txt
```